# HtmlEditorExtender text for FontSizeSelector and FontNameSelector is too small

Tags: asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using HtmlEditorExtender, among buttons "FontSizeSelector" and "FontNameSelector",
the font size is so small for the text in these buttons how do I increase it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this css style rule to your page

```
.fontnameclass select,
.fontsizeclass select
{
    font-size: 20px !important;
}
```